# LUKS partition recovery

Tags: partitioning, partition-recovery, luks

A drive with 2 partitions - 1st is plain ext4, second is encrypted LUKS.
The partition table has been overwritten. I've found the beginning of the second partition  , which i need to recover, thusly:

```
#hexdump -s 400000m -C /dev/sdc | grep LUKS
61d3dec850 79 c8 81 6d e5 4c 55 4b 53 40 49 aa 29 df de d7 |y..m.LUKS@I.)...|
```

then:

```
#losetup -o 0x61d3dec850 -r -f /dev/sdc
#losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0005]:477209 (/dev/sdc), offset 420166420560
```

ok so far, then this problem pops up:

```
#cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 luksrecover
Device /dev/loop0 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Please advice how to proceed. Is it wrong offset? Should I seek for the magic number 0xEF53 identifying ext4 as adviced here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103919/how-do-i-find-the-offset-of-an-ext4-filesystem ?

Mind you it's a 1TB drive so please I need an advice that does not force to scan the entire drive ( hours and hours) all over again if possible, such as testdisk which seems have no option to start at a specified offset to save time on scanning.
Thanx in advance.

P.S. This was close , but not quite: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177070/lvm-encrypted-partition-without-partition-table

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid you didn't find the correct offset of the LUKS partition. After LUKS should appear \xba\xbe and, in your hexdump, it is not so.

Try searching the disk with
LC_ALL=C grep -a -b -P 'LUKS\xba\xbe' /dev/sdc

If the partition data is still there, the output will be:
offset:LUKS....
with the correct offset (decimal) you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Your offset is wrong; it should be `0x61d3dec856`, the offset to `LUKS`; `0x61d3dec850` is the offset to the beginning of the line.